# How to let emacs treat .XXX as .c files?

Tags: emacs

I was working with .stp files and .d files, which define kernel probes in c-like syntax. So I would like them to be treated as C source files so I could see the lovely font highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples -- just put in whatever mode you need -- e.g., `c-mode`:

```
;; associates files with a particular mode.
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tex\\'" . lawlist-tex-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.todo\\'" . lawlist-org-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.done\\'" . lawlist-org-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.scratch\\'" . text-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("user_prefs\\'" . text-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.lisp\\'" . emacs-lisp-mode))
```

Comment: Appreciate it! I'll mark it as accepted soon enough:)